# Tangent plane of $f(x,y) := 6y+4x-x^3y$ in $(1,0)$

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

Let $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y) := 6y+4x-x^3y$

I also have to determine the function definition $\tau_{(1,0)}(x,y)$ of the tangent plane to the graph of the function $f$ at the point $(1,0)$.

I would have taken

$f_x(x,y) = 4-3yx^2$

$f_y(x,y) = 6-x^3$

Then I would have calculated

$\nabla f(1,0) = (4, 5)$

Then we get

$$\tau_{1,0} (x,y) = f(1,0) + \nabla f(1,0) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = 4 + (4 , 5) \begin{pmatrix} x - 1 \\ y-0 \end{pmatrix} = 4x + 5y $$

Therefore, the function definition $\tau_{1,0}(x,y) = 4x + 5y$

Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Looks right. More generally, if $f(x,y)=g(x,y)y+bx,$ then the plane at $(a,0)$ is $bx+g_x(a,0)y=ab.$

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot!